# How to phrase a jquery scroll function to work on one page but no other pages in a Wordpress website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

In a wordpress site, I removed the current-menu-item class to a long scrolling page, and added it back once the top section is above a certain height. This works well, but scrolling on any other page induces the addClass back on the first page navigation, as well as the current (visible) page. The site can be viewed at http://apurch.jvonhausen.com. I've tried to add if is_page('home'), but that has not worked to discriminate to which page this applies:

```
   $('#menu-item-15').removeClass('current-menu-item current_page_item');

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var navitem = $('#menu-item-15');
        var currentPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
        var sliderheight = $('.home_slider').height();
        navitem.removeClass('current-menu-item current_page_item').each(function() {
          var top = $(this).offset().top,
          bottom = top + $(this).height();
          if (currentPosition >= top && currentPosition <= bottom) {
            $(navitem).addClass('current-menu-item current_page_item');
          }
          if (currentPosition < sliderheight || !($('.home'))) {
            $(navitem).removeClass('current-menu-item current_page_item');
          }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) to check if the `body` element has the class of `home` and only apply the code if it does. WordPress adds useful classes to the body such as the `home` class the the home page.

```
if($("body").hasClass("home")) {
    $('#menu-item-15').removeClass('current-menu-item current_page_item');

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var navitem = $('#menu-item-15');
        var currentPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
        var sliderheight = $('.home_slider').height();
        navitem.removeClass('current-menu-item current_page_item').each(function() {
          var top = $(this).offset().top,
          bottom = top + $(this).height();
          if (currentPosition >= top && currentPosition <= bottom) {
            $(navitem).addClass('current-menu-item current_page_item');
          }
          if (currentPosition < sliderheight || !($('.home'))) {
            $(navitem).removeClass('current-menu-item current_page_item');
          }
      });
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) to check if you are on the home page before enqueuing or printing the script tag.